# Qt C++ Library for Windows and OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to experiment with the Qt library on Windows.  On their [downloads page](http://qt-project.org/downloads), I notice that the binaries built using VS2012 are available in two forms, with and without OpenGL.  What exactly is the difference between the two?  In the OpenGL version, do they have some special API implemented using OpenGL or does all of Qt rendering depend on OpenGL?  Also, is there a version of Qt that uses DirectX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Raman: The opengl variant is using the desktop opengl version just like with Qt4.

The non-opengl variant is using angle, and you need to have that installed alongside the DirectX SDK to get it working. Angle is an adapter between the directx and the opengles API. Only the latter is support directly by Qt, but unfortunately directx drivers tend to work better on Windows than the opengl(es) ones. There are no plans to support a directx backend inside Qt, so we leave with Google's Angle work in that regard.

As for providing some extra bit, there was a discussion about it recently on the mailing list, that this decision should not be build time, but more like run time. However, no one has stood up just yet to make that work. Hopefully, that will change soon. It is causing confusion for the end users just like, so do not feel alone. ;-)

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: So the OpenGL version of Qt uses the OpenGL drivers which are not so good for Windows.  The non-OpenGL version of Qt indirectly relies on DirectX but only because it uses a OpenGL -> DirectX emulator library.  Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

DirectX is supported via the [ANGLE](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL) based library.

Comment: I understand that but mu question is that on this link: http://qt-project.org/downloads, what is the difference between Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB) and Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB)

Answer (score 1):

Note that this has changed and as of Qt 5.5 the prebuilt binaries you can download from the Qt website are configured with the -opengl dynamic option. This is what @lpapp above was talking about. Qt defaults to choosing either native OpenGL drivers or ANGLE at run time now.

Qt internally uses OpenGL to render unless you specify otherwise now. You can also render custom OpenGL content using Qt's QOpenGLxxx functions and classes.

[For a simple introduction to Qt and OpenGL that covers this and more click here.](https://steventaitinger.wordpress.com/2015/11/24/part-1-modern-opengl-using-qt-5-5-tutorial)