# What is the difference between Qt Creator versions?

Tags: qt, opengl, version

When downloading from this site http://qt-project.org/downloads

There are different versions like versions with OpenGL and versions without OpenGL, what is the different between them ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113607

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago Google did develop a OpenGL emulation wrapper called ANGLE, to implement conformant WebGL on systems without a proper OpenGL installation, yet with sufficient Direct3D support. Qt makes internally use of OpenGL in some modules/classes. The non OpenGL downloads of Qt are linked with ANGLE to reliably enable this, even without proper OpenGL drivers on the system. The OpenGL versions of the download use the systems native OpenGL.